# Monitor apps power usage

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically access the `settings->about phone->battery usage` stuff?  We'd like to monitor how much power our app is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to programmatically access the settings->about phone->battery usage stuff?

Alas, no.

> We'd like to monitor how much power our app is using.

The excellent-but-flawed answer is the [Qualcomm MDP](http://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/behold-snapdragon-mdp) with the [Trepn power profiler](http://developer.qualcomm.com/dev/development-devices/trepn-profiler). Alas, this is expensive and has [a wholly inappropriate set of terms and conditions](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/03/28/open-letter-qualcomm-mdp.html), IMHO.

There is also http://powertutor.org/ and https://github.com/dvgrhl/BatteryCalibrator, though neither are as sophisticated as Trepn.