# Android Power Profiler

Tags: android, profiling

I need to perform power measurements for android applications. I tried "powertutor" and it gives the power consumption per every application. Yet, I don't know how accurate its readings are. Does anyone know how accurate it is?

Also, I have used the DDMS to profile the android application. I obtain the processes as memory info about it. Is there a way that i can know the power consumption per process in Android? (some rough estimation?) or is it impossible?

I really need to perform "power" profiling for android applications but I don't know how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor apps power usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019996/monitor-apps-power-usage)

Comment: @CommonsWare i need it specifically for android and i know it exists, i just want the experience of someone who tried it and knows how accurate it is... And most important is that i would like to know if there is some estimation that when u know the power consumption of the whole application, you can use the profiling data to know each method power consumption.

Comment: "knows how accurate it is" -- have you asked the authors? "you can use the profiling data to know each method power consumption" -- at best, profiling data will give you a rough idea of CPU power consumption, but there is more to power management than the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

In my academic research for measuring power consumption on Android, we use a power supply hooked up to the phone's battery terminals that outputs the voltage and current to a PC. Measure without the app to get a baseline and then compare against measurements with the app running. It's not extremely accurate, but it's the best way we know how.