# How to monitor power, cpu and battery usage of a Service

Tags: android, service, monitoring

I looking for an android application or some other way to monitor and check how much power my application, which contains a Service.

I found power tutor and smart monitor, but they only monitors applications and not services.

any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor apps power usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019996/monitor-apps-power-usage)